# Why is my loop continuing without waiting for async/await to complete?

Tags: javascript, async-await

So at a high level how I am expecting this to work.

1. Function1 will be kicked off by a user.
2. During the execution Function2 will be kicked off inside Function1.
3. Function2 will be kicked off for every loop of an array.
4. I need to wait for each Function2 to complete before moving on to the next loop.

Currently it is running Function2 the correct amount of times but it is not waiting for each previous to complete.

```js
async function1() {

      let index = 0
      for (const row of this.submissions) {
        if (row.EXCEL_CHECK === 1) {
          (async() => {
            let indexAdd = await this.function2(index)
          })();
        }
        index = index + indexAdd
      }
}

  async function2(inlineIndex) {
  
    // Create someArray
     try {
      await this.getSomeArray(something);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Try/Catch Error: ' + e);
    }
    let x = this.someArray.length - 1;
    return x;
    
  }
```

Note I only added the async arrow because I was getting this result when I tried just putting

```
let indexAdd = await function2(index)
```

Error:

```
'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts
```

Note I have simplified the functions for ease of explanation, but this call is being made deep in the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Function1` is already an asynchronous function, so you don't need to wrap `Function2` call with anonymous asynchronous arrow function.

So you can safely remove these:

```js
// - (async() => {
    let indexAdd = await this.function2(index)
// - })();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am still pretty new to Angular. I have elaborated further in my post now. I tried what you have there but it gave errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response @user68288, is `Function1` async or not? It seems you forgot to apply the async to `Function1`

Comment: Both Function1 and Function2 are set to async.

Comment: I think there might be a different issue in your code base. Because in async-await, this must be the correct behaviour.

Comment: I will mark this as right as it does answer the issue presented, I will dig into my code and see if I can ask a better question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  await (async() => {
        let indexAdd = await this.function2(index)
  })();
```

Just add another await with anonymous function.

Or you remove the async totally as func 1 is already async

```
//(async() => {
    let indexAdd = await this.function2(index)
//})();
```

And Make sure func1 is called with await

```
await function1();
```